# Windows Azure query not executing in android app

Tags: java, android, database, azure

I have an android app that has two queries next to each other that both populate private variables. I ran through it on the emulator and it crashed due to null pointer exception. After debugging it and tracing through the programs, it goes to the code below and skips over it entirely and goes to imgFavorite line. Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
            try {
                mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                          "https://classconnect.azure-mobile.net/",
                          "HzaUWkJBnWTXxCuREwxyQSaxJSyyJm51",
                          this
                    );
                // TODO: 3 Get the Mobile Service Table instance to use
                mUserTable = mClient.getTable(User.class);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                mEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("Email");

            mUserTable.where().field("email").eq(mEmail).execute(new TableQueryCallback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<User> result, int arg1,
                        Exception arg2, ServiceFilterResponse arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (arg2 == null){
                        if(!result.isEmpty()){
                            currentUser = result.get(0);
                            System.out.println(currentUser.getfName());
                    } else{
                        System.out.println("Error");
                    }
                    }
                }
            });

            mUserTable.select("email").execute(new TableQueryCallback<User>(){

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<User> result, int arg1,
                        Exception arg2, ServiceFilterResponse arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(arg2 == null){
                        for(User i : result){
                            allUsers.add(i.getEmail());
                        }
                    } else{
                        System.out.println("Error");
                    }
                }

            });


            imgFavorite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a call to your Mobile Service (such as the mUserTable.select or mUserTable.where calls), the callback you pass in as the parameter is exactly that, a callback.  The requests are made asynchronusly and the callback code is only executed when your Mobile Service responds.  If you put breakpoints within those callbacks, you'd see them executed once a response was received.  That is why it looks like the execution is skipping over that code and going right to the imgFavorite line.  As to why you're getting a null exception, you'll have to step through your code and see what line of code is actually triggering it.

Comment: I should've been more specific. I am getting a null pointer when I try to manipulate the "currentUser" that I am trying to get from the DB. I access it in a oncreateview fragment method. Should I have this method perform a wait or something to wait for a response from azure?

Comment: I'd consider displaying an activity indicator up so the user knows something is happening and then do the manipulation on the current User in the callback code once you know you've received it.